# Select occurence > 1 of css and don't show CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to select any occurrences after the first occurrence of `right_bar` in this html and not show it.

```
<div id="contain">

        <div class="post-18">
            <div id="post_content">
                    <!--content-here-->
            </div>
            <div id="right_bar">
                <!--right_bar-content-->
            </div><!--right_bar-->
            <div id="clear"> </div>
        </div><!--post_class()-->

        <div class="post-18">
            <div id="post_content">
                    <!--content-here-->
            </div>
            <div id="right_bar">
                <!--right_bar-content-->
            </div><!--right_bar-->
            <div id="clear"> </div>
        </div><!--post_class()-->
</div><!--contain-->
```

I'm slightly rusty on using the `nth selection` CSS3 selector, can anyone help?

I have tried the following to remove any occurrences of right_bar after the first occurrence (but it didn't work):

```
#right_bar:not(:first-child){
        display:none;
    }
```

By the way, this isn't a duplicate.

If someone can enlighten me. Thank you!

Comment: it pretty much *is* a duplicate, just with the twist of wanting to hide the other divs.

Answer (score 1):

`first-child` means "first of siblings" (on the same level), therefor you would need to do something like this:

```
.post-18:not(:first-child) #right_bar{
    display:none;
}
```

...because the `.post-18` are on the same level.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to user @Mark Resolved for his answer (as it helped me formulate an exact solution to fit my needs. Although his exact syntax didn't work, this worked for me, for my needs. Thanks!

```
.post:not(:first-child) #right_bar{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: well, for the code you've posted it would have been .post-18 ...